Test Case Action.async in Scala Play Framework
I'm working on Scala and the Play Framework project, and we are trying to write test cases using PlaySpec with GuiceOneAppPerTest, MockitoSugar, and BeforeAndAfterAll.
Here's the function we are testing:
def getRole(id: Long): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
  roles.get(id).map(response => {
    Ok(Json.obj("name" -> response.map(_.name)))
  })
}

And here is our test case:
"get Roles by Id" in {
  val roleId = 11L
  val fakeRequest = FakeRequest(GET, s"/role/id/$roleId")
  when(mockRoles.get(roleId)).thenReturn(Future.successful(Some(Role("admin"))))
     
  val result = controller.getRole(roleId).apply(fakeRequest)
    
  status(result) mustBe OK
  contentAsJson(result) mustBe Json.obj("name" -> "admin")
}

The test case is not working.
Output :
2024-12-16 11:01:36,218 [warn] c.z.h.u.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2024-12-16 11:01:36,219 [warn] c.z.h.u.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2024-12-16 11:01:41,431 [warn] a.a.CoordinatedShutdown - Coordinated shutdown phase [service-stop] timed out after 5000 milliseconds
[info] - get Roles by Id *** FAILED ***
[info]   org.mockito.exceptions.verification.SmartNullPointerException: You have a NullPointerException here:
[info] -> at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:393)
[info] because this method call was *not* stubbed correctly:
[info] -> at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:477)
[info] executionContext.prepare();
[info]   at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:393)
[info]   at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:302)
[info]   at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.dispatchOrAddCallbacks(Promise.scala:276)
[info]   at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.map(Promise.scala:146)
[info]   at controller.ProfileController.$anonfun$getRole$1(ProfileController.scala:5147)
[info]   at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder.$anonfun$async$1(Action.scala:339)
[info]   at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilderImpl.invokeBlock(Action.scala:441)
[info]   at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilderImpl.invokeBlock(Action.scala:439)
[info]   at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$9.apply(Action.scala:379)
[info]   at controller.HubbleTestCaseController.$anonfun$new$1(HubbleTestCaseController.scala:795)
[info]   ...
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 13 seconds, 301 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 1, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] *** 1 TEST FAILED ***
[error] Failed: Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         controller.HubbleTestCaseController
[error] (Test / test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 17 s, completed 16-Dec-2024, 11:01:41 AM

However, if we modify the function to remove async and handle the future synchronously, it works fine:
def getRole(id: Long): Action[AnyContent] = Action {
  roles.get(id).toJava.toCompletableFuture.get() match {
    case Some(value) => Ok(Json.obj("name" -> value.name))
    case None => BadRequest(Json.obj("error" -> "Data not found"))
  }
}

output :
[info] - should get Roles by Id
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 14 seconds, 275 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
[success] Total time: 15 s, completed 16-Dec-2024, 11:36:54 AM

Could someone please help us understand why the Action.async version is failing and how we can fix the test case for it?
scalaVersion "2.13.1",
sbt.version 1.3.8
jdk 11


What do you mean by The test case is not working?

What's the output of running the test? An assertion failure? What's the JVM, scala and playframework version you are using? Is it possible to share a minimal reproducible example? Or at least how you write the class that run the test?

@GastónSchabas
here is the error:
[info] - get Roles by Id *** FAILED ***
[info]   org.mockito.exceptions.verification.SmartNullPointerException: You have a NullPointerException here:
[info] -> at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:393)
scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
sbt.version = 1.3.8
jdk 11

@Jaygajjar please edit your original post with the complete error message. Also include your whole test class setup. It doesn't look like your test is failing because of assertions but rather because it's incorrectly setup, that's quite different.

@GaëlJ i have added output error in the querstion.

You still didn't show us how the test class is setup, how controller, mockRoles... are created and configured.

@Jaygajjar without the definition of the controller class and the roles class that the controller depends on, it's hard to guess. Based on the error message, sounds like you haven't correctly mocked something.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example
